# Complex MongoDB query with multiple OR

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb and I've built to make the following query.

```
1 AccessToken.where('resource_owner_id').equals(event.resource_owner_id)
2           .where('revoked_at').equals(undefined)
3           .or([ { scopes: /resources/i }, { scopes: new RegExp(event.resource,'i') } ])
4           .or([ { device_ids: [] }, { device_ids: event.body.id } ])
```

For this example I'm using Mongoose and coffescript.

Unluckily it doesn't work as I want, mainly for the `or` statement. What I want is the two `or` on row 3 and 4 being independent.

This means that the field `scopes` (row 3) must contain the string `resources` or the string stored in event.resource, meanwhile the field `device_ids` must be empty or contain the id `event.body.id`.

From the tests I've prepared I can see that the `or` command put all together. This means that when just one of the four or conditions is satisfied I get the document.

```
- { scopes: /resources/i }
- { scopes: new RegExp(event.resource,'i') }
- { device_ids: [] }
- { device_ids: event.body.id }
```

What I'm not able to reach is to split them in two groups so that both the conditions related to the field `scopes` and the conditions related to the field `device_ids` can be satisfied.

Hope the problem is well described.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `$where` unless you absolutely have to as performance is terrible.  Use a combination of the [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/) and [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/size/) operators instead:

**UPDATE** There's no Mongoose `and` method so you have to use the [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/and/) operator directly.

```
AccessToken.find({
    resource_owner_id: event.resource_owner_id,
    revoked_at: undefined,
    $and: [
        { $or: [{ scopes: /resources/i }, { scopes: new RegExp(event.resource,'i') }] },
        { $or: [{ device_ids: { $size: 0 } }, { device_ids: event.body.id }] }
    ]
}, callback);
```

Comment: This is similar to the solution I was coming out with. 

I updated the question as it was a bit more complex. The problem is that I would love to group the or in a way that one condition for scopes and one condition for device_ids should be satisfied.

Comment: @AndreaReginato To keep the two `$or` operations separate you have to put them in an `$and` operator.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll follow your detailed advices and let you know how things ended up.